# Simplifying Active States

Tags: javascript

I have a question that I believe comes down to method preference.

In the following code when the div parent element is clicked on, the div itself expands and also triggers an icon animation

```
  var slideSection6 = document.getElementById("manualsHandbooks").addEventListener("click", function()
                                                                               {
    if (this.parentElement.style.height == "60px" || this.parentElement.style.height == "")
    {
        this.parentElement.style.height = "215px";
        document.getElementById("MAHB").classList.add("active");
    }
    else
    {
        this.parentElement.style.height = "60px";
        document.getElementById("MAHB").classList.remove("active");
    }

}, false);
```

I was thinking about how easy it was just to add a class and change the state of the icon and I wanted to experiment and try adding the another click event just to the icon to make it animate on a click and active the parent element in the div as well. Basically the reverse of the above.

I thought it would be as simple as adding another condition to the if statement to the effect of

```
|| document.getElementId("MAHB").classList.add=("active") == true
```

But this doesn't work and I know it's not proper form.  Could someone get me started so I could figure this out?

Comment: Unrelated, but IMO embedding business logic in the height of an element is a really sketchy way of doing this. The worst-case should be class-based, even better to keep it out of the DOM altogether.

Comment: Is the `|| document.getElementId("MAHB").classList.indexOf("active") > -1` is what you are looking for?

Comment: No because on the second click the script will not run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Element.classList` has a `toggle` method that could make things a bit easier. If you want to check if a certain class is present, you can also use `classList.contains`.

I'd suggest not using the `height` of your elements to determine their current state. Why don't you alter the height using an `active` css class?

Your click handler could then be:

```
var button = document.getElementById("manualsHandbooks");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.classList.toggle("active");
    document.getElementById("MAHB").classList.toggle("active");
}, false);
```

You can read more about `classList` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Thanks so much!  Very new to JS.  Loving it, but can be so frustrating

Comment: Good to hear :) Make sure you learn to use your browser's Developer Tools to get a feel for what's going on. You can learn a lot from trying out stuff in the console.